# Caption does not fill the whole column

Tags: captions, subcaption, revtex

I am using the ReVTeX 4.1 template (for AIP journals), and while I was trying to add figures I noticed that the caption does not fill the whole column.

Is there a way to make caption fill the lines (and hence the column) as in the abstract or any other text in the body?

**UPDATE:**

I found out the problem: For some reason, loading the the subcaption package ruins the formatting of the figures captions in that they become unjustified & do not fill the whole line.

**Example:**
[image]

```
\documentclass[aip,reprint]{revtex4-1}

\draft 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup{labelsep = period}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Draft}

\author{LaTeX User}

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\maketitle 

 \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.55\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{}\vspace{0.3cm}
        \label{fig:1a} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.55\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:1b}
    \end{subfigure} 
    \captionsetup{justification   = justified,
        singlelinecheck = false}    
    \caption[]{\lipsum[1]}  
    \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If the `reprint` document class option is set, `revtex4-1` typesets  the document in two-column mode by default. Are you trying to use the full width of the textblock, i.e., both columns, for the figures and their caption(s)? If so, you should be using a `figure*` environment. Please clarify your typesetting needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some unknown reason, the figure is formatted in onecolumn mode.

BTW, you probably shouldn't do this.  Revtex4-1 uses `\unhbox` for a reason (like deliberately undoing the caption package formatting).

```
\documentclass[aip,reprint]{revtex4-1}

\draft 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\captionsetup{labelsep = period}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \par
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \begingroup
   \small\rmfamily
   \sbox\@tempboxa{%
    \let\\\heading@cr
    \@make@capt@title{#1}{#2}%
   }%
   \@ifdim{\wd\@tempboxa >\hsize}{%
    \begingroup
     \samepage
     \flushing
     \let\footnote\@footnotemark@gobble
     \@make@capt@title{#1}{#2}\par
    \endgroup
   }{%
     \global \@minipagefalse
     \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\unvbox\@tempboxa\hfil}% replaced \unhbox with \unvbox
   }%
  \endgroup
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip
}%
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Draft}

\author{LaTeX User}

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\maketitle 
 \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.55\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{}\vspace{0.3cm}
        \label{fig:1a} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.55\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:1b}
    \end{subfigure} 
    \caption[]{\lipsum[1]}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

This shows how to put the images and caption side-by-side.  I converted the figure into a minipage and moved it inside the abstract.  This is slightly more adaptable than an [H] figure using the float package.

```
\documentclass[aip,reprint]{revtex4-1}

\draft 

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{labelsep = period}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setcaptype}[1]{\edef\@captype{#1}}

\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \par
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \begingroup
   \small\rmfamily
   \sbox\@tempboxa{%
    \let\\\heading@cr
    \@make@capt@title{#1}{#2}%
   }%
   \@ifdim{\wd\@tempboxa >\hsize}{%
    \begingroup
     \samepage
     \flushing
     \let\footnote\@footnotemark@gobble
     \@make@capt@title{#1}{#2}\par
    \endgroup
   }{%
     \global \@minipagefalse
     \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\unvbox\@tempboxa\hfil}% replaced \unhbox with \unvbox
   }%
  \endgroup
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip
}%
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{Draft}

\author{LaTeX User}

\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr \textwidth-\leftskip-\rightskip}
  \hrule% DEBUG - show widfth of minipage
  \setcaptype{figure}%
  \vspace*{\intextsep}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.55\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{}\vspace{0.3cm}
        \label{fig:1a} 
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:1b}
    \end{subfigure} 
  \end{minipage}\hfill\begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \caption[]{\lipsum[1]}
    \label{fig:1}
  \end{minipage}
  \vspace*{\intextsep}
\end{minipage}
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```